# How to import file to shape in Pages

Tags: pages, iwork

I recently downloaded a resume template file for Pages, which has a some "shapes" in it and I'd like to add my own icons as shapes (for Github, StackExchange, etc), which I haven't come across any [docs](https://support.apple.com/guide/pages) about.

I tried importing an `.eps` file, but it just comes in as an image. Pages doesn't import `.svg`s.

Looked in

```
/Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Resources
```

And found

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  wheel   4.9M Mar 17  2022 shape_library.json
```

Which is full of vector paths:

```
    "178": {
      "id": 178,
      "shapePath": "M 478.593750 125.187500 C 416.293752 125.187500 399.593709 186.399994 399.593750 210.500000 C 399.593750 248.899999 422.693705 268.293742 435.593750 290.593750 C 437.793750 294.293750 434.706266 298.906298 430.406250 298.406250 C 350.606252 289.506250 305.412435 324.687501 274.312500 325.187500 C 256.412500 325.487500 227.393692 277.506254 204.093750 296.906250 C 187.893751 310.306250 184.693736 486.906254 314.593750 486.906250 C 444.393748 486.906250 485.500020 486.906250 485.500000 486.906250 C 485.500000 486.906250 595.406250 483.906311 595.406250 391.406250 C 595.406250 298.906250 539.406250 300.987528 539.406250 271.687500 C 539.406250 242.387499 591.606242 244.693736 595.406250 236.593750 C 599.606250 227.693750 582.312510 222.006271 582.312500 219.406250 C 582.312500 216.806250 600.106201 201.087508 595.406250 193.687500 C 590.906250 186.687500 582.187459 201.999990 556.187500 195.000000 C 553.487500 194.300000 551.512606 192.200014 550.812500 189.500000 C 545.912500 170.199999 536.193629 125.187523 478.593750 125.187500 Z M 478.593750 125.187500",
      "localizationKey": "Rubber Duck_178",
      "categories": {
        "37": {
          "position": 56
        }
      }
    },
```

But this is obviously not meant to be edited.

Pages doesn't have a directory in `/Library/Application\ Support/` or `~/Library/Application\ Support/`.

What am I missing?

## UPDATE

Based on answer from @grg, I found my way into the `db` that stores the user-defined shapes and am hoping to make some updates there.

1. Get into the `db`

`sqlite3 ~/"Library/Containers/com.apple.iWork.Pages/Data/Library/Application Support/com.apple.iWork.CloudKitStorage/com.apple.iWork.TSKCloudKitPrivateZone.db"`

2. Look around

```
sqlite> pragma table_info(TSDUserDefinedShapeLibraryShape);
0|identifier|TEXT|0||1
1|cloudKitMetadata|TEXT|0||0
2|needs_first_fetch|INTEGER|0|0|0
3|TSDUserDefinedShapeLibraryBezierPathStringKey|TEXT|0||0
4|TSDUserDefinedShapeLibraryName
```

```
sqlite> select identifier, TSDUserDefinedShapeLibraryNameKey   from TSDUserDefinedShapeLibraryShape;
E52A91BC-3774-45AE-B7A8-456EA04E4C0B|Envelope
E19F63AC-23B4-4495-B401-A83544A7AF37|Globe
7C133FEE-8C55-45B5-BB6A-D7A264898555|Location
9B7722F5-8029-4454-A8CA-AE6202BB5CA6|triangle
```

3. Make a modification

```
update TSDUserDefinedShapeLibraryShape set TSDUserDefinedShapeLibraryNameKey = "not a circle" where TSDUserDefinedShapeLibraryNameKey  = 'triangle';
```

4. Confirm updated

```
sqlite> select identifier, TSDUserDefinedShapeLibraryNameKey   from TSDUserDefinedShapeLibraryShape;
9B7722F5-8029-4454-A8CA-AE6202BB5CA6|not a circle
```

5. Quit and Restart Pages - updated name not there.

However if I update the name *within* pages, the new name shows up right away:

```
9B7722F5-8029-4454-A8CA-AE6202BB5CA6|treehouse
```

So it seems that Pages is writing to the db in realtime, but not reading from it. Perhaps it's the cloudkitMetadata that needs to change. Perhaps I just shouldn't be trying to use the application in this way.

#### Safety

To [backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675314/how-to-backup-sqlite-database) `db` before hacking at it:

```
.sqlite ~/"Library/Containers/com.apple.iWork.Pages/Data/Library/Application Support/com.apple.iWork.CloudKitStorage/com.apple.iWork.TSKCloudKitPrivateZone.db" \
    ".backup 'iword_cloudkit_backup_file.sq3'"
```

### Second Update

Possibly due to having disconnected from the internet, my database changes are now showing up after restarting the Pages application.

I can now successfully run `CRUD` commands on the db and as they will work if certain specs are met:

1. `location` needs to be a UUID of the correct format. Not sure what format that is. [This website](https://hashes.com/en/tools/hash_identifier) suggested the app is generating either version 1 or 4. I have tried generating my own and they don't seem to work. I can only `INSERT` if I use a `location` previously generated by the app.
2. Am still unsure if being connected to the internet makes any difference.
3. The `TSDUserDefinedShapeLibraryBezierPathStringKey` needs to be a [Bezier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). Not an svg path.

I have tried using a [tool to generate a Bezier curve from svg path](https://itchylabs.com/tools/path-to-bezier), but so far not in a way that renders correctly. In testing I copy-pasted paths from the `shapy_library.json` file referenced above.

Comment: If I can get this working, perhaps a python script like this could insert paths from svgs: https://gist.github.com/dreness/b5ebd1ebff092b124d343164c6217a98

Answer (score 4):

Pages does not support importing a shape file.

> If you created or customised a closed-path shape, you can save it to the shapes library.

https://support.apple.com/guide/pages-iphone/tancb0d1c0b3/ios

You can draw the shape yourself, then add it to My Shapes with the context menu.

[image]

Pages is a sandboxed application like most on macOS, so you won't find anything outside of its container(s) in `~/Library/Containers`. My Shapes are stored in
`~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iWork.Pages/Data/Library/Application Support/com.apple.iWork.CloudKitStorage/com.apple.iWork.TSKCloudKitPrivateZone.db`.

```
$ sqlite3 ~/"Library/Containers/com.apple.iWork.Pages/Data/Library/Application Support/com.apple.iWork.CloudKitStorage/com.apple.iWork.TSKCloudKitPrivateZone.db" \
    "select TSDUserDefinedShapeLibraryNameKey, TSDUserDefinedShapeLibraryBezierPathStringKey from TSDUserDefinedShapeLibraryShape;"
MyCustomShape|M 153.676079 367.646016 C 122.497427 367.646016 97.121058 402.035008 97.121048 444.405957 C 97.121048 486.776952 122.397495 521.134633 153.676079 521.134679 C 179.758225 521.134679 201.736961 497.157369 208.232483 464.579648 C 208.832069 461.381841 211.748833 459.083402 214.946632 459.083409 L 429.487259 459.083409 C 430.686447 459.083409 431.704483 460.101491 431.704483 461.300641 L 431.704483 483.379277 C 431.704483 484.578450 445.994766 490.874173 447.193893 490.874143 L 454.282791 490.874143 C 455.481979 490.874143 469.772202 484.578488 469.772171 483.379277 L 469.772171 461.300641 C 469.772171 460.101468 470.759018 459.083379 471.958176 459.083409 L 493.037491 459.083409 C 495.835587 459.083409 498.159103 456.791257 498.158981 453.993146 L 498.158981 434.818776 C 497.959122 432.020688 495.648209 429.697289 492.850113 429.697282 L 214.946632 429.697282 C 211.748825 429.697282 208.832039 427.398847 208.232483 424.201043 C 201.736923 391.623349 179.758202 367.646016 153.676079 367.646016 Z M 153.582394 389.349906 C 168.472199 389.349906 180.563934 403.615151 180.563919 421.203095 C 180.563919 428.198308 180.563904 460.676061 180.563919 467.671285 C 180.563919 485.259236 168.472199 499.555669 153.582394 499.555699 C 138.692585 499.555699 126.600851 485.259252 126.600866 467.671285 C 126.600866 460.676068 126.600880 428.198296 126.600866 421.203095 C 126.600866 403.615140 138.692581 389.349912 153.582394 389.349906 Z M 153.582394 389.349906
```

Comment: Great. Using that db, I can run `select * from TSDUserDefinedShapeLibraryShape;` to see my shapes. Can I also insert shapes into that db?