# Valid UUID for iWork database items

Tags: ios, pages, iwork

Starting with [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/452018/how-to-import-file-to-shape-in-pages), I am trying to insert my own Shapes into Pages and one of the
challenges is being to generate a valid [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/21.1/sqlreferencefornosql/using-uuid-data-type.html) for the `identifier`.

I have tried UUID version 1, 3, 4 and 5, none of which Pages seems to recognize as a valid UUID.

I learned that 3 and 5 can accept a namespace. So am wondering if there's a specific namespace that needs to seed the UUID when it's generated. Apple documents [it's own UUID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/uuid), which perhaps I could generate with X-Code, but I'm not sure.

This is one of the Pages-generated UUID's:

```
9B7722F5-8029-4454-A8CA-AE6202BB5CA6 | my_shape
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If I’m not mistaken (I don’t work with Pages much, but worked on similar issues previously), you can't simply import objects into the database.  That UUID **must** be generated by Pages (or the system) as a security precaution to prevent malicious code from being entered.  When you import via the prescribed tools, a valid UUID is created.